# Linear combination of affiliated random variables does not necessarily preserve affiliation

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Can anyone provide an example of affiliated random variables $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $Z_3$ such that $Z_1+Z_2$ and $Z_3$ are *not* affiliated? If possible, can you also explain your intuition for constructing your example?

Thanks a lot!

[EDIT] Some additional thoughts:

1. This won't work if $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $Z_3$ are jointly normal, because in that case affiliation is equivalent to non-negative covariance, and $$Cov(Z_1+Z_2,Z_3)=Cov(Z_1,Z_3)+Cov(Z_2,Z_3)\geq0$$.
2. If we think of $Z_3$ as an underlying parameter and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ as some signal about $Z_3$, then affiliation implies (i) the conditional densities $f_{Z_3|Z_1}(\cdot|z_1)$ and $f_{Z_3|Z_2}(\cdot|z_2)$ satisfy the monotone likelihood ratio property (MLRP), and (ii) $Cov(Z_1,Z_2)\geq0$. So we want an example where (i) a higher realization of $Z_1$ or $Z_2$ induces a higher posterior about $Z_3$, (ii) it is not generally true that a higher realization of the sum $Z_1+Z_2$ induces a higher posterior about $Z_3$.

Comment: What does affiliated mean?

Comment: I think there are a few equivalent definitions, e.g. the joint density is log-supermodular. If we assume $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ has joint density $f$ that is strictly positive and twice differentiable, it just means that all cross-partials of $\log f$ are nonnegative.